# Pleas help, im not sure whats wrong with the two lines of code

Tags: string

I know this is a super super simple thing but dont know why im getting this error. Im just trying to ask for a name and then execute a print command with the input.

```
name = input("whats your name?:")
print("hello,", name,"!")

whats your name?:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 0

^
```

SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
Unknown Error.

Answer (score 0):

Use `raw_input()` inplace of `input()`
Please find the modifications

```
name = raw_input("whats your name?:")
print("hello,", name,"!")
```